# Website in IIS locally and Domain Name bought from GoDaddy - What Next

Tags: web, iis, hosting, godaddy-api

I have been at this since last couple of weeks. After tiring efforts leading to nowhere, I am posting here.

I have a Website built and hosted in IIS locally. I just bought domain name from GoDaddy. I have my computer's public IP where the website in IIS is present. What are my next steps so that I can keep my computer as server and link with domain name? So that website is accessible publicly through domain name.

I saw a lot of posts with Web Hosting in Azure or other places, do I HAVE TO buy and host to make my site public?

I am a novice website builder and have very limited knowledge about this.

Comment: 1. Your computer's public IP can change. Many ISPs of your internet connection ask for extra charge if you want a static IP address. You can only consult them to learn the policies. 2. Using your own machine to host a site publicly is doable, but problematic. You can be hacked easily, and availability is also not guaranteed. That's why people/companies use a web hosting service provider.

Answer (score 0):

- first you need make sure your sever is secured, only open necessary ports
- go to another computer, in browser input public ip to see if you can open your webpage
- then in Godaddy you can add A record for your domain, to point your domain to your public IP,  refer to this GoDaddy document: https://ca.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238

If you are not comfortable or don't resource to do these, I suggest you host on Azure or other cloud providers

Comment: Thank you. I will follow the steps and see.

Answer (score 0):

You could host your application in either Azure VM or your local machine. After all, Could VM should be more convenient because you don't need spend a lot of time to handle network issue and you don't need physical space.

When you decide to host your application locally, you have to ensure your are using windows server OS, otherwise, you have 10 concurrent request limit.

Access the application via domain is quite simple.

1. You need to enable port like 80 in windows firewall.Promise your server are in DMZ and can be accessed externally
2. Create IIS binding header with null domain and your public address
3. Try to access your website via your public IP address
4. Point godday domain to your public IP address
5. Add your domain to your Site's binding host header->host name field

If you decide to host your application in IAAS like Azure VM, then you have to create inbound rule for your port number and allow port in windows firewall.  You also have to point your godday domain to your cloud VM's public IP address and create IIS binding with your domain. Finally, you should be able to access your website.